# Salesforce CSP site issue

Tags: community, api, csp, content-security-policy

Hi i have defined the few sites in the salesforce CSP settings but still i am getting the error as

```
    Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
```

all the sites are defined in the CSP settings of the Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the options are ticked & context is selected as required. 
And use a '*' for subdomains.

[image]